# How to get default pictures folder in sd card on android?

Tags: android

I have a little application that shows pictures from the web. I want my users to be able to save the pictures to the sd card but I don't want to save them in the root folder. Is there anyway to get the default picture folder in the sd card to save the pictures there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This method would do as desired. Works for me

```
private String getAlbumName() {
    return root folder name;
}

public File getAlbumDir() {
    File storageDir = null;

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {

        storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName());

        if (storageDir != null) {
            if (! storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                if (! storageDir.exists()){
                    Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
    }

    return storageDir;
}
```